# Picture of spider for identification

Tags: species-identification, species, arachnology

Would like to get spiders identified . Specimens can be sent for detailed examination if required .

[image]
Spider seen on floor inside house - at Phoenix USA
[image]
White off color spider on twigs and flowers of oleander tree with white flower in backyard of house at phoenix USA  - seen dropping off on disturbance and camoflouging with. White flowers. Picture can be magnified spider sitting on green stalk  below brownish dried flowers.

Comment: It is advisable to post one question(here specimen) a post.

Answer (score 2):

The first is a male Theridiid, probably Parasteatoda tepidariorum (see below)
[image]

https://bugguide.net/node/view/1320395/bgimage.

The second is one of the "flower spiders" in the Misumena/Misumenops/Misumenoides/etc. group of Crab Spiders.  It would take a better photo to get closer than that, since this is a young female and isn't showing the color marks that make it easier to ID.  There's a hint of patterning on the abdomen, but it isn't clear enough to ring any bells with me.  In a comment below, I'll include a link to the Bug Guide page for these spiders so you can look at it - the relatively useful marks for field observation are the greenish bands (if any) on the sides of the cephalothorax, the 'mask' (if any) over the eyes, and the pattern (if any) on the abdomen.  Also, the reddish 'racing stripes' on the sides of the abdomen of fully adult females can be helpful in working out which spider it is.  I suspect that for most of us, most of the time, "Flower Spider" is going to be good enough.

Comment: Here's the link.  I'm not inclined to favor any particular species, offhand, without a better look at the abdominal pattern that appears to exist.  https://bugguide.net/node/view/1957/tree  My best guess is that it's likely to be somewhere between Mecaphesa (unlikely) and Misumessus.

Comment: The trouble with these (and many other) spiders is that it usually takes a good look with a dissecting microscope to get a confident ID.  You could send it to someone for such a check, but I'm no longer current with active spider folks, and I can't suggest anyone offhand.  What you could do is to do a search on "thomisidae" "research" or "taxonomy" and see what pops up.  Check recent papers for the authors' names, and write off to one or more to see if they would help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

White one: Flower crab spider white, They can be all white or have purple or even pretty red stripes along the sides, kinda cool.

Comment: Thanks.  Kinda cool  .  Further I would like to know its scientific name . Else if someone can suggest the contact to send the specimen to know it's scientific name .